# Why does this incorrect pre_get_posts meta_query work for sort order?

Tags: meta-query, order, pre-get-posts

I've got a fairly complicated post type archive page that I need to order by two meta fields and the post title. To do that, I'm using `pre_get_posts` with a `meta_query` that simply tests for the existence of two meta-keys. It's entirely to allow for [the complex ordering](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/) required. This wasn't working until I accidentally used the wrong syntax.

Why does this code work? **Update: "Fixed" snippet to show the wrong-but-functioning code. h/t @SallyCJ. Update 2: Fixed the fixed snippet so keys are correct.**

```
<?php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_pre_get_posts' );
function wpse_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if( ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }

    if( is_post_type_archive( 'my-post-type' ) ) {

    $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
            'relation'      => 'OR',
            array( // this array shouldn't be here but is required for the ordering to work
                'meta_query_1'  => array(
                    'key' => 'cis_schools_is_model',
                    'type'  => 'numeric',
                    'compare'   => 'EXISTS',
                ),
                'meta_query_2'  => array(
                    'key' => 'cis_schools_district',
                    'compare'   => 'EXISTS',
                ),
            ),
        ));

        $query->set( 'orderby', array(
            'meta_query_1'      => 'DESC',
            'meta_query_2'   => 'ASC',
            'title'             => 'ASC',
        ));

    }
}
```

My expectation is that the extra array wrapping the two keyed meta queries (`meta_query_1` and `meta_query_2`) shouldn't be necessary like this:

```
<?php
$query->set( 'meta_query', array(
    'relation'      => 'OR',
    'meta_query_1'  => array(
        'key' => 'meta-key-1',
        'type'  => 'numeric',
        'compare'   => 'EXISTS',
    ),
    'meta_query_2'  => array(
        'key' => 'meta-key-two',
        'compare'   => 'EXISTS',
    ),
));
```

However, the first snippet works and the second doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, which first snippet? And I don't see anything wrong in your `meta_query`..

Comment: Sorry about that @SallyCJ. I've updated the first snippet to be accurate ("wrong" but working).

Comment: I tested your code, and both worked for me - the `orderby` was correct with and without the `array()` wrapping. Are you sure the second one didn't work for you? Or could it be because of the mismatched keys as in the question (snippet #1) - e.g. `model_school` should be `meta_query_1`.. ? In my tests, both snippets resulted in `GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) DESC, CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) ASC, wp_posts.post_title ASC`.

Comment: I'm using WordPress 4.9.8, if that helps. (And btw, ignore the `GROUP BY wp_posts.ID` part.)

Comment: Fixed the meta_query keys in the first example. They do match, I just did a horrible job of trying to anonymize the snippet.

Comment: In the *second* snippet, the `relation` is `OR`; but in the *first* snippet, the two meta queries are wrapped inside an inner `array` with no explicit `relation` set and hence it *defaults to* `AND`. So that might be the reason to why the *second* snippet "doesn't work".